# "toString()" retornando Null quando não deveria

Tags: java, string, orientação-a-objetos, null

Tenho a classe `Aluno`.

```
public class Aluno {

    private String nome;

    @Override
    public  String toString() {
        return this.nome;
    }
    //metodos getters e setters

}
```

Classe `Vetor`

```
public class Vetor {

    private Aluno[] alunos = new Aluno[5];

    public void Adiciona(Aluno aluno) {
        for(int i = 0; i < alunos.length; i++) {
            if(alunos[i] == null) { //encontrou uma posicao vazia
               alunos[i] = aluno;
               break;
            }
        }


    public int tamanho() {

        return this.alunos.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        if(this.alunos.length == 0) {
            return "[]";
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("[");

        for(int i = 0; i < this.alunos.length - 1; i++) {
            builder.append(this.alunos[i]);
            builder.append(", ");
        }

        builder.append(this.alunos[this.alunos.length - 1]);
        builder.append("]");

        return builder.toString();


        }
    }
```

Quando mando imprimir aqui, retorna todos os elementos dos vetores:

```
public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Aluno a1 = new Aluno();
        Aluno a2 = new Aluno();

        a1.setNome("Joao");
        a2.setNome("Maria");

        Vetor lista = new Vetor();
        lista.Adiciona(a1);
        lista.Adiciona(a2);

        System.out.println(lista);
    }
}
```

O resultado que retorna é esse:

> [Joao, Maria, null, null, null, null]

Comment: Não está errado. Você iniciou um vetor com 5 "espaços" e só preencheu dois, logo, o retorno dos outros espaços será null.

Comment: Como faço pra não imprimir? tentei != null, mas nao da certo

Comment: Se tentou, poderia ter colocado na pergunta pra dizermos o que está errado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[O `toString()` não deveria ser usado para isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101). Se a apostila incentiva esse uso, sinto muito. Mas vamos lá.

Precisa ter uma instrução que mande parar de listar o resto do *array* quando acha um nulo ou pelo menos filtrar ele:

```
builder.append("[");
if (this.alunos[0] != null) builder.append(this.alunos[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < this.alunos.length; i++) {
    if (this.alunos[i] != null) {
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(this.alunos[i]);
    }
}
builder.append("]");
return builder.toString();
```

Se quando achar um nulo, é garantindo que todos os seguintes também serão nulos, pode melhorar:

```
builder.append("[");
if (this.alunos[0] != null) {
    builder.append(this.alunos[0]);
    return "[]";
}
for (int i = 1; i < this.alunos.length; i++) {
    if (this.alunos[i] == null) break;
    builder.append(", ");
    builder.append(this.alunos[i]);
}
builder.append("]");
return builder.toString();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Build.java).

Também imprimia um item a mais, consertei isto.

Então eu verifico se o existe pelo menos um item e mando imprimi-lo (tem que por um `if` ali também).

Depois eu tento ver o resto (no laço) se não form nulos.

Como eu já imprimi o primeiro item (o 0 no *array*), não preciso imprimir novamente, então começo no 1.

Essa separação do primeiro item é necessária por causa da vírgula. Claro que poderia ter começado do 0 e ir até o `length - 1` para não imprimir o último (o último é sempre o `length - 1`, já que começa do zero, muita gente confunde isso, o último só seria exatamente o `length` se o *array* começasse do 1.

Isso nem é computação, é matemática básica, mas como o operador de comparação usado é o "menor que", ele já tira este último) e aí teria que imprimir o último separado (com o `if` para evitar o nulo).

Dá na mesma fazer antes ou depois, eu prefiro antes, até porque se o primeiro for nulo já posso matar o resto, se for garantido que depois de achar um nulo, todos serão. Em códigos reais, poderia fazer uma função para cuidar disso.

Se tivesse um controle da quantidade de itens existentes no *array*, poderia matar a execução dentro do próprio `for` e nem precisaria do `if`.

Eu tiraria esses `this` que são completamente desnecessários.

Há outros problemas menores no código.