# Qual é a função do método toString()?

Tags: java, string

Qual é a função do `toString()` no Java? Por que fazemos `System.out.println(compObjeto)` e no `main()` (supondo que há um objeto para a classe comp chamado `compObjeto`), ele faz *print* do `toString()`?

```
public class comp {

    private String nome;
    private Data aniversario;

    public comp (String n, Data a){
        nome=n;
        aniversario=a;

    }

    public String toString(){

        return String.format("O teu nome é %s , e a fazes anos no dia %s", nome, aniversario);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dúvidas sobre o método toString() da classe Object](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10893/d%c3%bavidas-sobre-o-m%c3%a9todo-tostring-da-classe-object)

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre usar Object.toString() e String.valueOf()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208388/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-usar-object-tostring-e-string-valueof/)

Comment: Quase achei duplicata, mas depois vi que o foco lá é outro.

Comment: De acordo @maniero

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Como o nome diz, o que ele faz é resultar em um texto que expresse o que é esse objeto, por isso todo objeto possui este método.

Há alguma controvérsia sobre o uso conceitual certo.

O meu entendimento, e de muitas [pessoas muito mais experientes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42396672/221800) e com formação (no sentido amplo, não de estudo certificado apenas) muito melhor que eu, entende que isso é uma função de depuração ou no máximo pra conversão de dados para serialização ou alguma atividade bem específica que tem mais a ver com o mecanismo do que com a regra de negócio.

Há quem discorde disso, e em Java parece haver a cultura de ser mais que isso, o que demonstra uma cultura esquisita porque é uma linguagem que tenta fazer o que é mais correto, mesmo que nem sempre seja prático, e este junto com mecanismo de exceções e outras coisas na linguagem, procuram o mais prático mesmo que conceitualmente esteja errado.

Há ainda quem ache que pode fazer qualquer coisa nele, pode até mesmo escrever no console ou em uma tela GUI. Isso eu acho que todo mundo que entende alguma coisa sobre desenvolvimento de software, concorda que é abuso, pelo menos conceitualmente. E tudo que está errado conceitualmente em código real, complexo, um dia explode na sua cara. O código do AP está certo nesse ponto.

Mas pelo conceito anterior ele está errado porque ele está definindo regra de negócio, ele está resultando em algo pra ser usado na aplicação, provavelmente com interação com o usuário, que não é o objetivo do `toString()`.

Esse método deveria apenas retornar a identidade simples do objeto. Alguma coisa que indique que objeto é esse, qual o seu conteúdo importante de forma mais básica possível.

Se quer uma mensagem formatada, crie um método para retornar isso. Se quer usar algo padronizado, até pode usar um `toString(alguma coisa)` ([assim com uma assinatura diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) do que está em todo objeto) que já é algo que não é usado para atender as necessidades do mecanismo. Mas pode ser outro método também. Java não tem uma padronização para isso. Java foi criado em uma época que muita coisa ainda não era percebida como errada.

Claro que no exemplo usado não é algo tão crítico porque faz um pouco o que precisa, mas tem muito penduricalho.

Vamos pegar a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) fornecida [pelo Math na resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10896/101) em outra pergunta:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

Essa forma é representativa do objeto? É conciso? Eu acho que não, até [respondi lá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212797/101). O Java até incentiva o certo, mas muita gente não interpreta desta forma na documentação. Portanto eu discordo muito da resposta do Math lá.

Tem mais:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

Aí diz que deve usar o nome da classe. Claro que dar algum valor de identidade é mais útil que só o nome, terá vantagens. A implementação padrão desse método na maioria das classes é assim, retorna o nome da classe e não a identidade do objeto ([entenda a diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101)). É pra fins de depuração mesmo. Até uma reflexão (bem) de pobre.

Pensa, se um dia precisar retornar um texto diferente, o que fará? Trocar esse texto? E se a aplicação depende daquele texto específico para fazer algo? Afinal o método é de mecanismo, ele pode ser usado para qualquer coisa que envolva a representação e ela deve ser estável, o resultado faz parte do contrato da [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101). E se precisar mudar mesmo, teria que criar um outro método, viraria uma bagunça porque está misturando funções.

Se enfeitar o texto do `toString()` fosse o certo o `Integer` deveria ser assim:

```
public String toString() {
     return String.format("O valor do objeto é %s", String.valueOf(value);
 }
```

É isso que está fazendo na classe da pergunta. Isso é muito errado.

Eu prefiro assim:

```
public class comp {
    private String nome;
    private Data aniversario;
    public comp (String n, Data a) {
        nome = n;
        aniversario = a;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s - %s", nome, aniversario);
    }
    public String getTextual() {
        return String.format("O teu nome é %s , e a fazes anos no dia %s", nome, aniversario);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/ToString.java).

Talvez até poderia ser: `String.format(nome);`, eu acho que o aniversário exagerado aí, não faz parte da identidade. O método secundário foi só um exemplo simples, em aplicação real eu nem sei se faria isso, nem sei se teria algo assim no objeto, eu acho que pode ser uma regra de negócio *plugável*, mas isso já é outro assunto.

Comment: Qual é o objeto no meu exemplo ? é o construtor ?

Comment: @PedroGouveia não, nesse código não existe objeto ainda, só existe a classe. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101. Construtor é outra coisa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101. Nesta classe você só tem um construtor e o `toString()` definido. Pelo que está na pergunta em `System.out.println(compObjeto)`, a variável `compObjeto` guarda o objeto que só existirá em tempo de execução.

Comment: muito obrigado por todo o trabalho! Ja agora qual é a vantagem do to string ser   return String.format("%s - %s", nome, aniversario); , e não ser logo return String.format("O teu nome é %s , e a fazes anos no dia %s", nome, aniversario);?

Comment: o toString é so um standard caso haja algum problema ou assim ?

Comment: @PedroGouveia melhorei a resposta, é uma questão de conceito e uso adequado do mecanismo. Ele não foi feito para passar mensagens para o usuário, qdo usa o conceito errado pode até funcionar, mas um dia paga um preço por isso. Este método é padrão para uso  interno da plicação. É para pegar uma informação sem firulas, pra tratar brutalmente. Tem gente até que acha que não deveria fazer parte da hierarquia de tipos e ser um detalhe de implementação, mais uma convenção de chamada. Mas aí o assunto já fica mais profundo que sua pergunta fala.

Comment: muito obrigado ja entendi!

Comment: Ok nao queria ser muito chato mas, so para ter a certeza ,basicamente o toString "define" uma String para uma classe ?

Comment: @PedroGouveia eu prefiro a definição mais formal, ele define um texto que representa o objeto (e não a classe). Um texto descrito não é o mesmo que representativo. O que você usou é descritivo. Note que tem gente que acha isso certo, mas nunca vi um bom argumento que diga porque é certo.

Answer (score 9):

## [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

```
public String toString()
```

> Retorna uma representação textual do Objeto. O resultado deve ser uma
>   representação concisa mas informativa que é fácil para uma pessoa ler.
>   Recomenda-se que todas as subclasses substituam este método. O método
>   `toString` para a classe `Object` retorna uma seqüência de caracteres
>   consistindo no nome da classe da qual o objeto é uma instância `@`, e
>   a representação hexadecimal não assinada do
>   código `hash` do objeto([Exemplo](https://ideone.com/IcsZDu)). Em outras palavras, esse método retorna uma
>   seqüência de caracteres igual ao valor de:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Nessa resposta do SO-EN, tem uma serie de exemplos que podem esclarecer melhor as suas dúvidas.

- [How to use the toString method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Comment: Qual é o objeto no meu exemplo ? é o construtor ?

Comment: @PedroGouveia editei a pergunta com uma pergunta do SO-EN. Lá tem uma serie de respostas que podem ajudar a entender melhor como funciona o `ToString`

Answer (score 9):

O método `toString()` serve para gerar uma identidade textual que corresponda ao objeto alvo.

Toda vez que o objeto alvo precisa ser convertido para um String, normalmente a fim de imprimi-la no console ou num arquivo de log, o método `toString()` é chamado.

Todo objeto Java já possui um implementação default do `toString()`. Quem é responsável por esta implementação é a classe `Object`, a qual todas as classe estendem por padrão. Na implementação default, quando faz-se um print do objeto é impresso o FullName da classe seguindo por "@" + o endereço de memória do objeto.

Por isso, que as vezes é necessário sobrescrever o método `toString()`, já que a impressão da implementação default não é muito amigável.

Comment: O construtor no exemplo que eu dei neste caso é o objeto ?