# Como calcular o aproveitamento de um time de futebol em um campeonato?

Tags: java, algoritmo, matemática

Estou querendo fazer um calculo de media de aproveitamento de um time de futebol em um certo campeonato, por exemplo, meu time jogou duas partidas e ganhou uma. Ele teria 3 pontos de 6 pontos disputados e um aproveitamento de 50%.

```
public final class Time {
    private String nome;
    private int vitorias = 0;
    private int empates = 0;
    private int derrotas = 0;
    private int numPartidas = 0;
    private int pontos;
    private float aproveitamento;

    public Time(String nome) {
        this.setNome(nome);
    }
    public void ganharPartida(){
        this.setVitorias(this.getVitorias() + 1);
        this.setPontos(this.getPontos() + 3);
        this.setNumPartidas(this.getNumPartidas() + 1);
    }
    public void empatarPartida(){
        this.setEmpates(this.getEmpates() + 1);
        this.setPontos(this.getPontos() + 1);
        this.setNumPartidas(this.getNumPartidas() + 1);
    }
    public void perderPartida(){
        this.setDerrotas(this.getDerrotas() + 1);
        this.setNumPartidas(this.getNumPartidas() + 1);
    }


    //GETTER E SETTER

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getVitorias() {
        return vitorias;
    }

    public void setVitorias(int vitorias) {
        this.vitorias++;
    }

    public int getEmpates() {
        return empates;
    }

    public void setEmpates(int empates) {
        this.empates = empates;
    }

    public int getDerrotas() {
        return derrotas;
    }

    public void setDerrotas(int derrotas) {
        this.derrotas = derrotas;
    }

    public int getNumPartidas() {
        return numPartidas;
    }

    public void setNumPartidas(int numPartidas) {
        this.numPartidas = numPartidas;
    }

    public float getAproveitamento() {
        return aproveitamento;
    }

    public void setAproveitamento(float aproveitamento) {
        this.aproveitamento = pontos;
    }

    public int getPontos() {
        return pontos;
    }

    public void setPontos(int pontos) {
        this.pontos = pontos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Time{" + "nome=" + nome + ", vitorias=" + vitorias + ", empates=" + empates + ", derrotas=" + derrotas + ", numPartidas=" + numPartidas + ", pontos=" + pontos + ", aproveitamento=" + aproveitamento + '}';
    }





}
```

Comment: E qual sua dúvida?

Comment: Como eu aplico essas regras no aproveitamento

Comment: Aplica onde? O que no código tem algum problema, alguma dificuldade?

Comment: Parece me que ele tá com dificuldade em criar a lógica só para a percentagem de aproveitamento de pontos. Seria algo como `(vitorias*3 + empates*1) / numPartidas*3`

Comment: É isso mesmo, obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O cálculo é o de menos, matemática básica. A lógica está um pouco complicada. Na verdade eu tiraria a maioria dos métodos. Há uma escola de aprendizado que manda criar *getters/setters* para tudo. Eu e muita gente considera isto errado. Só deve criar se for absolutamente necessário. Eu tiraria todos eles. Tirei o que fazia nenhum sentido. As consultas aos campos pode ser útil, amas alterá-los parece erro de projeto. Deixa os métodos que que estabelecem o resultado de uma partida fazer isso.

Me parece que o aproveitamento não deve ser modificado, por isso criei um método privado para calculá-lo e o chamei sempre que uma informação é alterada. Na verdade eu prefiro nem fazer assim, acho mais interessante calcular quando preciso do dado, assim diminui o tamanho da estrutura e facilita o código, mas sei lé se isto era requisito. Eu tentei obter mais informações sobre o que precisava mas não obtive sucesso.

Eu não usei os métodos *getters/setters* internamente porque geralmente eles só são úteis para acesso externo.

Mudei o nome que dá o resultado já que [o `toString()` não serve para isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101).

Foi legal ter colocado o `final`, em geral as pessoas não colocam e quase sempre é o melhor a fazer.

Espero que a resposta sirva para além do problema específico já que a estrutura do projeto está muito baseada nas tais "boas práticas" difundidas por aí e que está formando programadores ruins porque elas não formam programadores, criam apenas copiadores de receitas. Na verdade tem outras coisas que poderiam ser feitas de forma melhor, mas para um exercício simples não vem ao caso.

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Time time = new Time("Meu time");
        time.ganharPartida();
        time.empatarPartida();
        time.perderPartida();
        time.ganharPartida();
        System.out.println(time.Estatisticas());
    }
}

public final class Time {
    private String nome;
    private int vitorias;
    private int empates;
    private int derrotas;
    private int numPartidas;
    private int pontos;
    private float aproveitamento;

    public Time(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public void ganharPartida() {
        vitorias++;
        pontos += 3;
        numPartidas++;
        CalcAproveitamento();
    }
    public void empatarPartida() {
        empates++;
        pontos++;
        numPartidas++;
        CalcAproveitamento();
    }
    public void perderPartida() {
        derrotas++;
        numPartidas++;
        CalcAproveitamento();
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public int getVitorias() {
        return vitorias;
    }
    public void setVitorias(int vitorias) {
        this.vitorias = vitorias;
        CalcAproveitamento();
    }
    public int getEmpates() {
        return empates;
    }
    public void setEmpates(int empates) {
        this.empates = empates;
        CalcAproveitamento();
    }
    public int getDerrotas() {
        return derrotas;
    }
    public void setDerrotas(int derrotas) {
        this.derrotas = derrotas;
        CalcAproveitamento();
    }
    public int getNumPartidas() {
        return numPartidas;
    }
    public void setNumPartidas(int numPartidas) {
        this.numPartidas = numPartidas;
        CalcAproveitamento();
    }
    public float getAproveitamento() {
        return aproveitamento;
    }
    private void CalcAproveitamento() {
        this.aproveitamento = (float)pontos / (numPartidas * 3) * 100;
    }
    public int getPontos() {
        return pontos;
    }
    public void setPontos(int pontos) {
        this.pontos = pontos;
    }
    public String Estatisticas() {
        return "Time{" + "nome=" + nome + ", vitorias=" + vitorias + ", empates=" + empates + ", derrotas=" + derrotas + ", numPartidas=" + numPartidas + ", pontos=" + pontos + ", aproveitamento=" + aproveitamento + '}';
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/xySk5J). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ofiucwjk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/TeamScoring.java).

Provavelmente eu faria assim:

```
public final class Time {
    private String nome;
    private int vitorias;
    private int empates;
    private int derrotas;
    public Time(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public void ganharPartida() {
        vitorias++;
    }
    public void empatarPartida() {
        empates++;
    }
    public void perderPartida() {
        derrotas++;
    }
    public String Estatisticas() {
        return "Time{" + "nome=" + nome + ", vitorias=" + vitorias + ", empates=" + empates + ", derrotas=" + derrotas + ", numPartidas=" + (vitorias + empates + derrotas) + ", pontos=" + (vitorias * 3 +  empates) + ", aproveitamento=" + (float)(vitorias * 3 +  empates) / ((vitorias + empates + derrotas) * 3) * 100 + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: "Eu não usei os métodos getters/setters internamente porque geralmente eles só são úteis para acesso externo."

Comment: O uso externo significaria o que?

Comment: @BrunoOliveira fora da classe.