# Retornar dados de um subobjeto

Tags: java, arraylist, objetos

Segue abaixo o que implementei ate então:

```
public class Interface
{    
    private List<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList();   
    private List<Tarefa> tarefas = new ArrayList(); 
    Menu menu = new Menu();

    public void program()
    {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Menu.apresentaMenu();
        int opcao = entrada.nextInt();
        while(opcao!=5)
        {
            switch(opcao)
            {
                case 1:
                System.out.println("Cadastro de usuario");
                System.out.println("Forneça o nome");
                entrada.nextLine();
                String nome = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Forneça o cpf");
                String cpf = entrada.nextLine();
                Usuario umUsuario = new Usuario();
                umUsuario.setNome(nome);
                umUsuario.setCpf(cpf);

                usuarios.add(umUsuario);
                break;

                case 2 :
                entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Busca de usuario");
                System.out.println("informe o cpf do usuario ");
                cpf = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println(usuarios.size());


                for (int i = 0;i<usuarios.size();i++)
                {   if(usuarios.get(i).getCpf().equals(cpf)){
                        Usuario temp = usuarios.get(i);
                        System.out.println(temp.getNome());

                        while(opcao!=0)
                        {
                           switch(opcao)
                            { 
                                case 1:
                                System.out.println("1.Inserir Tarefa");
                                System.out.println("Forneça a descriçao");
                                entrada.nextLine();
                                String desc_tarefa = entrada.nextLine();
                                System.out.println("Forneça o prazo");
                                String prazo_tarefa = entrada.nextLine();
                                Tarefa umaTarefa = new Tarefa();
                                umaTarefa.setDesc_tarefa(desc_tarefa);
                                umaTarefa.setPrazo_tarefa(prazo_tarefa);

                                tarefas.add(umaTarefa);
                                temp.setTarefa(umaTarefa);

                                break;

                                case 2:
                                System.out.println("2.Listar Tarefas");
                                System.out.println(tarefas.size());
                                System.out.println(temp.getTarefa());
                                break;
```

Na linha `System.out.println(temp.getTarefa());` estou tentando retornar a descrição da tarefa porém ele me trás o endereço do objeto na memória.

```
public class Usuario
{
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private Tarefa tarefa;

    public void setTarefa(Tarefa tarefa)
    {
        this.tarefa = tarefa;
    }

    public Tarefa getTarefa()
    {
        return this.tarefa;
    }
```

e

```
public class Tarefa
{
    String desc_tarefa;
    String status_tarefa;
    String prazo_tarefa;

     public void setDesc_tarefa(String desc_tarefa)
    {
        this.desc_tarefa = desc_tarefa ;
    }


    public void setPrazo_tarefa(String prazo_tarefa)
    {
        this.prazo_tarefa = prazo_tarefa ;
    }

     public String getDesc_tarefa()
    {
        return this.desc_tarefa;
    }

    public String getPrazo_tarefa()
    {
        return this.prazo_tarefa;
    }

}
```

Como posso fazer para retornar o atributo do objeto tarefa?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer acessar um atributo de `Tarefa`, não basta acessar apenas o objeto em si, mas o campo dentro dele. No seu caso, os *getters* de Tarefa retornam uma `String`. Assim, uma solução para seu problema pode ser:

```
System.out.println(temp.getTarefa().getDesc_tarefa());
```

Answer (score 2):

Vamos começar usando o termo correto: [o que você chama de atributo na verdade chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). E você não quer nem um atributo e nem um campo, quer chamar um *getter* que te dá um valor. Há muitos questionamentos se é correto usar um *getter*, mas isto é outro assunto (que [tem aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101)).

`getTarefa()` retorna um objeto do tipo `Tarefa`, e sendo um objeto se você mandar imprimir mostrará apenas um endereço de onde ele está (salvo se tiver um `ToString()` mostrando algo diferente, mas [quase sempre isto é errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101), e assim como no caso do *getter*, quase todo programador faz errado). Para chamar a descrição do objeto você deve pegá-lo e chamar o método que te dá a descrição (`getDesc_tarefa()`). Não tem como ele adivinhar o que você quer. Em programação você tem que dizer em detalhes tudo o que deseja. No texto da sua pergunta diz que quer a descrição, no seu código não diz, apenas está dizendo para imprimir o objeto, não a descrição. Assim descreve corretamente:

```
System.out.println(temp.getTarefa().getDesc_tarefa());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/SubObject.java).

Os nomes de métodos e campos fogem do padrão normalmente usado em Java. Tem outras melhorias possíveis neste código.