# Como checar e converter valores em IEnumerable de um query da database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lista

Eu tenho uma que que retorna uma tabela em IEnumerable e tenho uma determinada coluna que retorna valores "A" para Activo, "C" para cancelado e assim por diante. 
Gostaria de converter esses valores para o correto antes de chegar na view. Tipo ao inves de "A" apareceria para o usuário "Activo".
Como fazer isso?
Qualquer ajuda é bem vindo.

Seria algo parecido com o codigo abaixo, mais aplicado em uma lista IEnumerable.

```
public string GetStatusPagamento(int fileCodigo)
 {
  var statusPgto = _context.GetFileByFileCode(fileCodigo).Select(s => 
   s.StatusPagamento).FirstOrDefault();

    switch (statusPgto.ToString())
    {
    case "A":
      return "Ativo";

    case "D":
      return "Ativo";

    case "E":
      return "Cancelado";

    case "M":
      return "Reembolsado";

    case "R":
      return "Ativo";

    case "X":
      return "Cancelado";

    default:
      return "Indefinido";
  } 
}
```

Comment: Fica muito difícil de responder pois qualquer um que ler sua pergunta pode imaginar seu código de forma diferente. Você precisa fazer as perguntas bem detalhadas, dê uma revisada pois tem algumas palavras faltando na pergunda, adicione seu código e saiba mais sobre como perguntar aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Adicionei um código de exemplo. Eu precisava fazer algo assim, mas em uma lista do tipo IEnumerable.

Comment: @NilsonMartins Você quer fazer esta "conversão" para todos os itens de `statusPgto`. É isso?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `statusPgto`?

Comment: Isso a conversão seria para todos os itens. É uma lista de string "IEnumerable<string>"

Comment: Ok, estava no texto da pergunta, não reparei. O que me levou a questionar foi o `statusPgto.ToString()`, usado no código.

Comment: Considerou a ideia de dar um override no .ToString() do [StatusPagamento] para fazer essa conversão?

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves e se em outro contexto precisar de outra forma? Na verdade toda vez que alguém usa este método para formatar dados um panda morre em algum lugar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101

Comment: Bem observado, @Maniero...você tem razão. +1

Comment: Obrigado @RonaldoAraújoAlves, override ToString era a solução que procurava.

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero, override ToString era a solução que procurava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução que eu encontrei foi criar outro atributo chamado "SwitchStatusPagto" no meu modelo que faz um caso de switch de estados e eu chamo esse atributo diretamente na minha View.

```
public string SwitchStatusPagto
    {
      get
      {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StatusPagto))
        {
          switch (StatusPagto)
          {
            case "A":
            case "D":
            case "R":
              return "Ativo";
            case "E":
            case "X":
              return "Cancelado";
            case "M":
              return "Reembolsado";
            default:
              return StatusPagto;
          }
        }
        return string.Empty;
      }
    }

<td>@Html.DisplayFor(fr => itemRequisicao.SwitchStatusPagto)</td>
```

Nota: "return string.Empty" foi necessário para evitar a erro de Null Reference, se os dados forem nulos.