# Listar algo de um construtor

Tags: java, método, construtor

Tenho um código em Java que cria um cliente na classe `Cliente`:

```
public class Cliente {
String nomeCompleto;
String dataNas;
String email;
String senha;    
}
```

então tenho o construtor desse `Cliente`

```
 public static void incluirCadastro() {
    // cria um novo cliente da classe Cliente;
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    cliente.nomeCompleto = Reader.readStringNotNull("Digite seu nome completo: ");
    cliente.dataNas = Reader.readStringNotNull("Digite sua data de nascimento - DD/MM/AAAA: ");
    cliente.email = Reader.readStringNotNull("Digite seu email: ");
    cliente.senha = Reader.readStringNotNull("Digite uma senha: ");
}
```

agora eu preciso de um método que liste o cliente criado, como posso fazer? Quero que seja um método fora do `incluirCadastro()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não deve sobrescrever o método `toString()` para fazer isto, [explico em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101).

Você deve criar um método qualquer com um nome que faça sentido indicando que está retornando os dados formatados. Você não diz bem o que significa listar, mas de qualquer forma não deveria listar na tela. Essa listagem será sempre da mesma forma em todos os contextos por toda a visa da aplicação? Será que essa listagem deve fazer parte deste objeto mesmo? Mesmo que faça então especifique o formato que deve ser listado antes de qualquer coisa, e depois monte isto neste método específico, um exemplo:

```
public String listaDados() {
    return "Nome: " + nomeCompleto + "\nNascimento: " + dataNas + "\nEmail: " + email;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/ListData.java).

Embora eu não sei nem se esta é uma boa solução. Deveria ter uma forma de pegar os dados individuais e você formatar como quer em outro lugar. Quem disse que é para separar com vírgula em todo lugar? Ou quebrar linha ou dar espaço, ou colocar todos os campos, nesta ordem, etc. Pra mim quase sempre a presença deste método em uma classe que determina uma entidade de negócio já é *design* ruim.

Na verdade o método inicializador está errado também porque ele está tratando da interface com usuário dentro dele, isto não deveria ocorrer, é acoplamento indevido. E o mais correto seria criar um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode sobrescrever o método `toString()` retornando uma String concatenada com os dados que você quer... Exemplo:

```
public String toString(){
   return "Nome: " + this.nomeCompleto + ", Nascimento: " + this.dataNas + ", Email: " + this.email;
}
```

Sobre o método construtor acredito que você possa fazer isso de um jeito melhor...
O método construtor precisa ter o mesmo nome da classe, ou seja você não criou um construtor ali (Pelo que eu entendi), para criar o construtor em si seria:

```
public Cliente(String nomeCompleto, String dataNas, String email, String senha){
   this.nomeCompleto = nomeCompleto;
   this.dataNas = dataNas;
   this.email = email;
   this.senha = senha;
}
```

Dessa forma os valores que você recebe do teclado você passa como parâmetro na criação do objeto

Ou então você pode criar um construtor sem parâmetros e setar os mesmos depois...