# IMC em java, ajuda com um erro

Tags: java, classes

O que esta errado nesse código, não consigo imprimir o calculo do IMC ? Erro esta nas ultimas linhas da Classe Pessoa.

```
package exe_3_ques_02;

//import import java.util.Set;

 import class exe_3_ques_03.Pessoa;

 public class Exe_3_Ques_02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(" Exercícios – Construindo Classes ");
     System.out.println(" Questão 2 ");
     System.out.println("=========================\n");
    //=========================================

     Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa("Diego", 23, 1.70f, 72f, "Masculino"); //, 23, 170, 72, M

        System.out.println(" Nome: " + pessoa.getNome());
        System.out.println(" Idade: "  + pessoa.getIdade());
        System.out.println(" Altura: " + pessoa.getAltura());
        System.out.println(" Peso: "   + pessoa.getPeso());
        System.out.println(" Sexo: "    + pessoa.getSexo());            

        System.out.println(" IMC" + pessoa.toString()); //            
        System.out.println("=================");

    }
}
```

CLASSE PESSOA

```
 package exe_3_ques_02;


  public class Pessoa {
   private String nome, sexo;
  private int idade;
  private float altura, peso;


public Pessoa() {
    this.nome  = " "; 
    this.idade  = 0;
    this.altura  = 0;
    this.peso   =  0;
    this.sexo = " ";

}

 public Pessoa(String nome, int idade, float altura, float peso, String sexo) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
    this.altura = altura;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.sexo = sexo;

}
   //=================
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

 public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
   //=================
  public int getIdade() {
    return idade;
}

  public void setIdade(int idade) {
    this.idade = idade;
}
   //=================
  public float getAltura() {
    return altura;
}

public void setAltura(float altura) {
    this.altura = altura;
}
  //=================
  public float getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

  public void setPeso(float peso) {
    this.peso = peso;
}
  //=================

   public String getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

  public void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}
  //=================
  //    calculo
public String calculoIMC (){
    double calculo;
    calculo = peso / (altura * altura); 

    if (calculo <= 18.5) { 
return ("Seu IMC é "+calculo + "  abaixo do normal!"); 
} 
    else if ((calculo > 25.0) && (calculo <= 30.0)) { 
return ("Seu IMC é " +calculo + "  acima do normal!"); 
} 
    else if (calculo > 30) { 
return ("Seu IMC é " + calculo + "  obesidade!"); 
}  

}

  //================

@Override
public String toString(){ 
    return " de : "+this.nome + " esta: " + calculo; // ERRO!

   }


   }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Comment: Editei com um print do erro

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável `calculo` não existe no método `toString`. Você precisa cirar ela e definir o valor de acordo com os dados

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    double calculo;
    calculo = this.peso / (this.altura * this.altura);

    return " de : " + this.nome + " esta: " + calculo;
}
```

Mas esse código pode gerar uma exceção se a altura for 0 e, portanto, o peso será divido por 0 gerando uma *ArithmeticException*

Comment: Entendi e fazendo essa modificações a saída ficou  /*  IMC de : Diego esta: 24.913494110107422 */ como faria pra alem de sair o valor do IMC, sair tbm se esta obeso ou abaixo do peso ?

Comment: Você pode chamar a função `calculoIMC`: `return " de : " + this.nome + " esta: " + calculo + "\n" + this.calculoIMC();`

Comment: return " de : " + this.nome + " é: " + calculo + "\n" + this.calculoIMC(); // assim ?

Comment: É, não está igaual ao que comentei?

Comment: Editei com outro print com o trecho do código e o erro

Comment: Retire o `if (calculo > 30)` deixando apenas o `/* ... */ } else { /* ... */`

Comment: Costamilam, deu certo!

Answer (score 3):

A variável calculo está inicializada dentro do método Calculo IMC. Variaveis inicializadas dentro de métodos não podem ser reconhecidas fora deles. Por isso, quando você chama a variável calculo em outro método, nesse caso, o toString, gera o erro.

Você pode resolver isso inicializando a variável calculo na classe e não dentro do método.