# Obter um item de uma lista referenciada

Tags: c#, lista, referência

Estou tentando obter os itens de uma lista genéria que passo por referência à uma classe, mas só tenho como retorno o nome do meu projeto concatenado com a classe. 
Segue abaixo um fragmento de código demonstrando como estou criando e passando a lista por referência.

```
readonly Class.Orders order = new Class.Orders();
readonly Class.Items items = new Class.Items();

  Class ItemsList
  {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int Quantidade{get; set;}
  }

  List<Items> list = new List<Items>();

  .
  .
  .

   public void AdicionaItens() //Se produto já existe na lista, apenas somo a quantidade
   {
      int index = list.FindIndex(x=> x.ID == items.prod.ID);
      if(index == -1)
      {
        list.Add (Items {ID = items.prod.ID, Quantidade= items.prod.Quantidade});
      }
      else
      {
        list[index].Quantidade += qtd;
      }
   }

   public void EnviaLista()
   {
     orders.Imprimir(ref list);
   }
```

Abaixo segue a Classe qual desejo passar a lista por referência

```
StringBuilder sbString = new StringBuilder();

public void Imprimir(ref List<T>ListaSeparado)
{
  foreach(var i in ListaSeparado)
  {
    sbString.AppendLine(i)
  }
}
```

Entretanto ao ver os dados adicionados ao `StringBuilder` eu tenho como resultado o nome do meu projeto + o nome da classe (`ProjectTest.ClassTest.ItemList`).

O que devo fazer para acessar corretamente os itens da lista?

Comment: O que você queria que aparecesse exatamente?

Comment: Eu estava tentando obter o ID e a Quantidade dos itens na Lista do metodo Imprimir...

Comment: Entendi. Outra dúvida: esse `ItemsList` seria o mesmo que o `Items`?

Comment: Não, na verdade a classe `items` tem algumas consultas e validações dos Itens... Já a Classe `ItemsList` seria uma classe local, somente para que eu possa criar a lista com os resultados de `Items`... Não sei se ficou claro...

Answer (score 0):

> sbString.AppendLine(i);

Quando você adiciona a instância no `StringBuilder` implicitamente você está fazendo um `i.ToString()` para adicionar o objeto ao `StringBuilder`, por isso aparece a classe e o namespace.

Uma alternativa é alterar essa linha de código para essa, por exemplo:

```c#
sbString.AppendLine($"ID: {i.ID}. Quantidade: {i.Quantidade}");
```

Comment: Ronaldo, tentei implementar dessa maneira, mas eu não consigo "ver" as propriedades(ID e Quantidade) da Lista.

Comment: Realmente, é uma lista de itens genéricos. Nesse caso, esse método `Imprimir`, que usa um `List<T>` de parâmetro...que tipos de itens pode vir de parâmetro? Dependendo, vc pode utilizar uma Interface como parâmetro, e essa interface teria um método `string GetDescricao()` (ou coisa do tipo), que vc utilizaria na hora de dar o `AppendLine()`

Comment: @Leonardo conseguiu?

Comment: ainda não, mas agora eu estou conseguindo "ver" as propriedades da lista usando o `.ForEach` do LINQ,  `ListaSeparado.ToList().Foreach( p=>{...})`

Answer (score -1):

Faça o overload do método ToString() para obter uma string correta.

```
class ItemsList
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public int Quantidade{ get; set; }

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return $"ID: { ID }. Quantidade: { Quantidade }";
   }
}
```

Além disto, o método `Imprimir(ref List<T> ListaSeparado)` não precisa ser passado usando a keyword `ref`

Classes em C# são passados por padrão como referência, diferente de estruturas.

Também faria um adendo quanto ao nome da classe. Ele tem um nome de `ItemList` porém faz referência a apenas um item. O `List<ItemList>` que realmente é a lista. O nome da classe deveria ser apenas `Item`, por exemplo, o que faria sentido já que é um único item.

Comment: Downvote anônimo é sempre muito interessante e útil, obrigado a quem o fez.

Comment: Não fui eu portanto não sei o motivo do downvote, mas o que eu **acho** que pode ter sido é que algumas pessoas são contra alterar o `ToString()` para formatação de dados. [Segue um link útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212758/144579).

Comment: Não vejo como fazer tendo uma lista de itens genéricos. A não ser que fosse uma lista de uma interface que dispõe de uma função para formatação. Ou mudar a função imprimir para ser uma extensão de IList<ItemList>