# Array list de classe pai com duas subclasses diferentes

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Criei um programa para o seguinte exercício:

> Exercício: Faça um programa para registrar clientes de uma empresa de um contador. 
>   É importante armazenar informaçÕes dos clientes, como nome, endereço, telefone e e-mail.
>
> Além disso deve-se ressaltar que o contador atende tanto pessoa física quanto jurídica, que se diferem pelo fato da primeira possuir CPF e a segunda um CNPJ. O programa deve registrar 
>   os clientes indefinidamente até que o usuário não mais desejar.
>
> No momento do cadastro, o programa 
>   deve perguntar ao usuário qual o tipo de cliente quer registrar, após isso, o programa deve exibir um relatório com todos os clientes registrados da seguinte forma:
>
> tipo: física
>   nome:
>   cpf:

O código ficou o seguinte:

```
public class Cliente{
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private String telefone;
    private String email;

    public Cliente(String nome, String endereco, String telefone, String email){
        this.nome=nome;
        this.endereco=endereco;
        this.telefone=telefone;
        this.email=email;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }
    public String getEndereco(){
        return endereco;
    }
    public String getTelefone(){
        return telefone;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }
}

public class PessoaFisica extends Cliente{
    private String cpf;

    public PessoaFisica(String nome, String endereco, String telefone, String email, String cpf){
        super(nome, endereco, telefone, email);
        this.cpf=cpf;
    }
    public String getCpf(){
        return cpf;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "tipo: fisica";
    }
}

public class PessoaJuridica extends Cliente{
    private String cnpj;

    public PessoaJuridica(String nome, String endereco, String telefone, String email, String cnpj){
        super(nome, endereco, telefone, email);
        this.cnpj=cnpj;
    }
    public String getCnpj(){
        return cnpj;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "tipo: juridica";
    }
}

import java.util.*;

public class MainContador{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int op=1;
        int tipo;
        List<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner dado = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println("Opcoes de cadastro:\n(1)pessoa fisica.\n(2)pessoa juridica");
            tipo = dado.nextInt();
            dado = new Scanner(System.in);

            if(tipo==1){
                System.out.println("Nome:");
                String nome = dado.nextLine();
                dado = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Endereco:");
                String endereco = dado.nextLine();
                dado = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Telefone:");
                String telefone = dado.nextLine();
                dado = new Scanner(System.in);  

                System.out.println("Email:");
                String email = dado.nextLine();
                dado = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Cpf:");
                String cpf = dado.nextLine();
                dado = new Scanner(System.in);  

                PessoaFisica pf = new PessoaFisica(nome, endereco, telefone, email, cpf);

                listaClientes.add(pf);  
            }
            else if(tipo==2){
                System.out.println("Nome:");
                String nome = dado.nextLine();
                dado = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Endereco:");
                String endereco = dado.nextLine();
                dado = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Telefone:");
                String telefone = dado.nextLine();
                dado = new Scanner(System.in);  

                System.out.println("Email:");
                String email = dado.nextLine();
                dado = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Cnpj:");
                String cnpj = dado.nextLine();
                dado = new Scanner(System.in);  

                PessoaJuridica pj = new PessoaJuridica(nome, endereco, telefone, email, cnpj);

                listaClientes.add(pj);  
            }

            System.out.println("Para cadastrar outro cliente, digite 1, para sair digite outro numero qualquer.");
            op = dado.nextInt();
            dado = new Scanner(System.in);
        }while(op==1);

        for(int i=0; i<listaClientes.size(); i++){
            Cliente c = listaClientes.get(i);

            if(c.toString()=="tipo: física"){
                System.out.println(c.toString());
                System.out.println("\nNome:" + c.getNome());
                System.out.println("\nEndereco:" + c.getEndereco());
                System.out.println("\nTelefone:"+c.getTelefone());
                System.out.println("\nEmail:"+c.getEmail());
                //System.out.println("\nCPF:"+c.getCpf());
                System.out.println("\n___________________\n");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(c.toString());
                System.out.println("\nNome:" + c.getNome());
                System.out.println("\nEndereco:" + c.getEndereco());
                System.out.println("\nTelefone:"+c.getTelefone());
                System.out.println("\nEmail:"+c.getEmail());
                //System.out.println("\nCNPJ:"+c.getCnpj());
                System.out.println("\n___________________\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comentando as linhas de `c.getCnpj()` e `c.getCpf()` o programa roda normalmente, mas aí não consigo exibir esses valores do meu objeto. A duvida é, na hora de compilar, o método não é encontrado nos objetos. Por que o método `getString()` é encontrado e o `getCpf()` ou `getCnpj()` não? Qual o problema?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

Tem vários erros conceituais aí e por isso causa o problema. Quase todo mundo comete o erro conceitual que cometeu, alguns até insistem que está certo, e se for apresentar para alguém avaliar pode ser que seja o que a pessoa quer. E o o erro que obteve já mostra como isso está errado. Se fosse modelado da forma correta não teria esse erro.

Tem um detalhe que me chamou atenção, o enunciado não manda fazer herança, não diz nada que precisa ter classes separadas para cada coisa, por que fez isto?

Pessoas não deveriam herdar de cliente porque afinal ser cliente é um papel de uma pessoa e não uma pessoa, assim como pessoas podem ser outras coisas que não um cliente, então isto não faz sentido. Ou você cria pessoas e as compõem com o papel de cliente, ou ainda usa o papel de cliente e associa com uma pessoa física ou jurídica. Ou cria uma classe `Cliente` que é o que o enunciado pede e só, trate se é física ou jurídica ali dentro mesmo. Tudo leva a crer que o intuito do exercício é isto, e se não for ele está mal formulado. Como `Cliente` é um papel ele não deveria ter nome, endereço, etc., quem tem essas coisas são pessoas, físicas ou jurídicas. Mas como o enunciado diz para ser assim ele provavelmente está tratando o cliente como uma pessoa, então não tem porque criar a pessoa de forma isolada.

Se fizer isto o problema deixa de existir, porque é um problema causada pela modelagem errado, corrigi-lo é legitimar o problema.

Para explicar para você o que acontece, é que na sua lista de clientes tem as duas pessoas, então alguns objetos tem o CPF, outro possuem o CNPJ, você não pode acessar `CPF` na `PessoaJuridica` e não pode acessar o `CNPJ` na `PessoaFisica`, como o erro indica, simplesmente porque o objeto não tem isso.

Para acessar o método que deseja o objeto tem que ser do tipo que está esperando. Então teria que fazer um *cast* para transformar o `Cliente` que não tem o método que quer em uma das duas pessoas que tem:

```
System.out.println("\nCPF:" + ((PessoaFisica)c).getCpf());
```

E

```
System.out.println("\nCPF:" + ((PessoaJuridica)c).getCnpj());
```

Mas tem outro erro. Esse [`toString()` está conceitualmente errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101), este método não foi criado para isto, é gambiarra e uma das piores formas de uso dele que eu já vi. Este método é para mostrar uma forma muito simples, isto é, sem formatação, algo que identifique o objeto, por isso o padrão é até o endereço do objeto, assim dá uma identidade única. O seu uso além de apresentar uma dado formatado, que não é o objetivo dele, também perde identidade, objetos diferentes são impressos com a mesma informação. Resolveu seu problema, mas jogou fora a funcionalidade desse método.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Deveria ter um dado em `Cliente` que define inequivocamente que tipo de pessoa ele é e que possa ser pego com semântica específica para isto, que só o `Cliente` sabe o que é, não algo que qualquer `Object` sabe que é o caso do `toString()`.

Note que não tem um método chamado `getString()`. [O `toString()` existe em todo `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), e todo objeto deriva de `Object`, então todos eles tem esse método.

Aí, já que terá um campo (e possivelmente *getters*, aqui nem vou discutir se deveria usar isto) para definir o tipo da pessoa, porque não ter uma campo com o número do documento desse cliente? E pode ser um campo só. Mas poderia ter dois se achar muito importante, no exercício não diz nada sobre isso.

Mas se insistir em manter essas classes não use o `toString()` dessa forma, basta fazer isto:

```
if (c instanceof PessoaFisica) {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/InheritanceElement.java).

Minha sugestão é fazer o código ficar conceitualmente certo, isto o simplificaria enormemente e resolveria o problema sozinho. Eu aproveitaria e eliminaria as duplicações que tem nele.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código tem vários problemas e melhorias que podem ser feitas, mas em resumo, a resposta da sua pergunta é: Porque você está dizendo que `c` é uma instância de `Cliente` e essa classe não tem os métodos `getCpf` e `getCnpj`. Para utilizar esses métodos você precisa informar qual a classe utilizada, como por exemplo:

```
System.out.println("\nCPF:" + ((PessoaFisica ) c).getCpf());
```