# Problema para utilizar um "System.out" em um objeto

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, objetos, polimorfismo, print

Estou tentando dar um `System.out.println` em um objeto que eu tenho (mesmo com o `toString()` na classe)
estou obtendo:

> Predio [nome=LS, aptos=[[Lmodel.Apartamento;@7ba4f24f,
>   [Lmodel.Apartamento;@3b9a45b3, [Lmodel.Apartamento;@7699a589,
>   [Lmodel.Apartamento;@58372a00, [Lmodel.Apartamento;@4dd8dc3]]

Meus *models*:

Predio:

```
package model;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Predio {
    private String nome;

    private Apartamento[][] aptos;

    public Predio(int qtdAndares, int aptosPorAndar, String nome) {
        this.aptos = new Apartamento[qtdAndares][aptosPorAndar];
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void adicionarApto(int andar, Apartamento apto) {
        if (andar >= this.aptos.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("O prédio só tem " + this.aptos.length + " andares");
        }
        // encontra a primeira posição não preenchida
        int i = 0;
        while (i < this.aptos[andar].length && this.aptos[andar][i] != null)
            i++;
        if (i >= this.aptos[andar].length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Andar " + andar + " já está com todos os apartamentos cadastrados");
        }
        this.aptos[andar][i] = apto;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Predio [nome=" + nome + ", aptos=" + Arrays.toString(aptos) + "]";
    }



}
```

Apartamento:

```
package model;

public class Apartamento {
    private Integer qtdQuarto, qtdBanheiro, qtdCozinha, qtdSala, numeroApt;



    public Apartamento(Integer numeroApt) {
        this.numeroApt = numeroApt;
    }

    public Integer getNumeroApt() {
        return numeroApt;
    }

    public void setNumeroApt(Integer numeroApt) {
        this.numeroApt = numeroApt;
    }

    public Integer getQtdQuarto() {
        return qtdQuarto;
    }

    public void setQtdQuarto(Integer qtdQuarto) {
        this.qtdQuarto = qtdQuarto;
    }

    public Integer getQtdBanheiro() {
        return qtdBanheiro;
    }

    public void setQtdBanheiro(Integer qtdBanheiro) {
        this.qtdBanheiro = qtdBanheiro;
    }

    public Integer getQtdCozinha() {
        return qtdCozinha;
    }

    public void setQtdCozinha(Integer qtdCozinha) {
        this.qtdCozinha = qtdCozinha;
    }

    public Integer getQtdSala() {
        return qtdSala;
    }

    public void setQtdSala(Integer qtdSala) {
        this.qtdSala = qtdSala;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Apartamento [qtdQuarto=" + qtdQuarto + ", qtdBanheiro=" + qtdBanheiro + ", qtdCozinha=" + qtdCozinha
                + ", qtdSala=" + qtdSala + "]";
    }


}
```

meu main:

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

import model.Apartamento;
import model.Predio;

public class app {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite o nome do Predio: ");
        String nomePredio = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de Andares do Predio: ");
        int qtdAndares = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de Apartamentos por andar: ");
        int aptosPorAndar = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Digite o prefixo de numeração dos Apartamentos: ");
        int prefApt = scanner.nextInt();

        Predio predio = new Predio(qtdAndares, aptosPorAndar,nomePredio);


        for (int andar = 0; andar < qtdAndares; andar++) {
            for (int apto = 0; apto < aptosPorAndar; apto++) {
                int numero = andar * prefApt + apto;
                // leia todos os dados que um apartamento precisa e passe todos para o construtor
                predio.adicionarApto(andar, new Apartamento(numero));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(predio);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está chamando esse [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) (que aceita um `Object`) porque não tem um método que manda imprimir a representação textual de depuração de um *array* de `Apartamento`, tem só um que imprime um *array* de `Object` que imprime exatamente isto que está aparecendo, afinal um `Object` é algo genérico. Se você quer algo diferente disto tem que escrever um código que percorra o *array* e imprima do jeito que você quer, até porque o `toString()` não serve para o que está achando que ele serve.

O [uso do `toString()` está errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101), mas como provavelmente aprendeu errado em algum lugar e as pessoas tendem a continuar fazendo errado o que aprenderam em primeiro lugar provavelmente não vai querer resolver isto. Espero que a resposta ali ajude entender que o conceito todo está errado.

A solução é ter um método diferente que monte para você os dados manualmente fazendo um laço e pegando o que deseja do *array* e dos elementos contidos nele. Esquece essa ideia de mandar imprimir o objeto e vai sair do jeito que deseja.

Inclusive não cometa o erro conceitual do objeto fornecer algo com *layout* específico, o objeto só deve fornecer os dados, o *layout* deve ser dado por algo externo, até porque para cada situação será um *layout* diferente.

Existe uma solução automática com reflexão, mas ela é lenta e fácil fazer errado, em geral é uso errado para economizar digitação e não resolverá seu problema de forma específica que é o que deseja.

Comment: Obrigado estou tentando modificar o codigo com suas dicas e removi o toString, mas com isso entrei em um outro problema, creio que terei de fazer uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Pode fazer, estamos aí pra isso.