# Aplicação de área do círculo: método mostra que nem todos os caminhos do código retornam valor

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho um código que realiza o cálculo da área do círculo em três objetos insaciados em `AppCírculo`, só que o método `getArea()` que deve retornar a área do círculo com o cálculo, só que o Visual Studio diz que nem todos os caminhos do código retornam valor, mensagem oriunda do erro CS0116 que não entendo.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace Aplicacao1
{
    public class Circulo
    {
        private double raio;
        private double area;

        public double getRaio()
        {
            return this.raio;
        }

        public void setRaio(double raio)
        {
            this.raio = raio;
        }

        public double getArea()
        {
            Circulo circulo1 = this;
            Circulo circulo2 = this;
            Circulo circulo3 = this;
            circulo1.area = 3.14159 * (raio * raio);
            circulo2.area = 3.14159 * (raio * raio);
            circulo3.area = 3.14159 * (raio * raio);
        }

        public string toString()
        {
            return raio + " " + area + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

```
using static System.Console;

namespace Aplicação1
{
    public class AppCirculo
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Circulo circulo1 = new Circulo();
            Circulo circulo2 = new Circulo();
            Circulo circulo3 = new Circulo();

            Write("Digite o raio do círculo 1: ");
            circulo1.setRaio(double.Parse(ReadLine())); 

            Write("Digite o raio do círculo 2: ");
            circulo2.setRaio(double.Parse(ReadLine()));

            Write("Digite o raio do círculo 3: ");
            circulo3.setRaio(double.Parse(ReadLine()));

            WriteLine(circulo1.ToString());
            WriteLine(circulo2.ToString());
            WriteLine(circulo3.ToString());
            ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public double getArea()` é um método com retorno `double` mas, faltou você colocar isso no seu código cade o `return` com o valor?

Comment: ficaria `return this.area`?

Comment: Então Carlos não sei qual é o retorno e como quer finalizar esse método ... só que deve ter um `return` com um determinado valor do tipo `double`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic queria retornar um valor `double`

Comment: Eu não sei porque você está fazendo 3 variaveis de circulo apontando para a própria objeto e depois fazendo a mesma operação ...! não é só retornar ??? aquela operação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você usa um tipo como retorno na [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) você tem que retornar um objeto daquele tipo em qualquer situação que aconteça na execução do método. Em geral este erro ocorre quando você retorna em um caminho mas não em outro, ou seja, tem uma parte condicional que faz o retorno e outra condição que não faz. Mas neste caso nem tem nada condicional, então deveria retornar alguma coisa de forma simples, mas no caso não tem retorno algum.

Ou então a solução é mudar o tipo do método e dizer que ele retorna `void`, neste caso não precisa retornar nada mais, porém não pode usar este método onde se espera algum retorno.

Pelo método eu tentaria tentar adivinhar o que ele deveria fazer, então pelo nome eu diria que tem que deixar o tipo `double` no método `getArea()` e ter um `return`. Mas aí eu teria que decidir o que retornar, e complicou porque esse método faz um monte de coisa mas não pega área do círculo, então nem sei o que retornar. Percebeu que mesmo que conserte esse erro seu código ainda estará confuso?

Eu vou chutar que o método seria assim, mas provavelmente isto é um erro (não faz sentido ter o método deste jeito). A classe toda é confusa.

```
public double GetArea() => 3.14159 * raio * raio;
```

Note que eu mudei o nome para ficar do jeito que se costuma fazer me C#. E tirei um monte de coisa que achei que não faz sentido. E usei uma sintaxe onde o retorno é implícito, assim não precisa usar o `return`, mas ele está retornando assim mesmo, ele retorna justamente o cálculo contido ali, seria o mesmo que fazer:

```
public double GetArea() {
    return 3.14159 * raio * raio;
}
```

E se for pensar bem em C# o mais certo é usar uma propriedade e não um método para fazer isto, assim:

```
public double Area => 3.14159 * raio * raio;
```

E o raio deveria ser assim:

```
public double Raio { get; set; }
```

E nem precisa do campo `raio` que é criado automaticamente. Assim não precisa dos métodos *getter/setter* que criou que não é idiomático em C#.

Não vejo porque o campo `area` deva existir, se acha que deve então deveria justificar.

leia também sobre construtores, porque isto também está errado na classe, de fato eu considero que o uso de *setter* até mesmo na propriedade é equivocado para este exemplo. Acredito que está aprendendo fazer errado e tentei te dar várias dicas do que pode melhorar. Pesquise aqui no site mais sobre tudo o que está tentando fazer, vai aprender muito, não prossiga sempre aprender o jeito certo de fazer as coisas porque isto irá consolidar e sempre continuará errando,

Normalmente [usar o `ToString()` do jeito que está fazendo é considerado abuso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101), neste caso nada exagerado, mas pode ser considerado errado.

Tem outros problemas no código que não impedem o funcionamento ou que não são perceptíveis se você não digitar dados errados, mas não vou tentar resolver todos eles aqui.

Pra te dar um parâmetro do que seria um código bom para isto. Analise com cuidado pra ver tudo o que pode melhor no que está fazendo:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Circulo {
    public Circulo(double raio) => Raio = raio;
    public double Raio { get; }
    public double Area => 3.14159 * Raio * Raio;
    public string Imprima() => Raio + " " + Area + " ";
}

public class AppCirculo {
    static int Main() {
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo 1: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var valor)) return 1;
        var circulo1 = new Circulo(valor);
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo 2: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out valor)) return 1;
        var circulo2 = new Circulo(valor);
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo 3: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out valor)) return 1;
        var circulo3 = new Circulo(valor);
        WriteLine(circulo1.Imprima());
        WriteLine(circulo2.Imprima());
        WriteLine(circulo3.Imprima());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Lj3FAT). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UrXTVx). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/Circle.cs).

Comment: Como se livrar da IDE1006 que diz "Regra de violação de nomenclatura"?

Comment: Imagino que está na minha resposta, caso não você deve abrir uma outra pergunta. Cada problema deve estar em uma pergunta diferente.

Comment: O uso de propriedades é em uma próxima questão, onde tenho que fazer uma aplicação da área do círculo e utilizar propriedades para a mesma questão, ou seja, a mesma questão feita em duas formas diferentes.

Comment: `ToString` foi um erro meu.

Comment: A forma sem propriedades em C# quase sempre é errada.

Comment: Usei ```public double GetArea() {
    return 3.14159 * raio * raio;
}``` usei assim e quando foi compilar apareceu`Aplicacao1.Circulo, Aplicacao1.Circulo, Aplicacao1.Circulo`

Comment: Eu editei a resposta e coloquei mais dicas. Seu código tem muitos problemas, eu acho até que vou reescrevê-lo pra você ver como fica bem.

Comment: Você uso propriedades no código?