# Exceção sem tratamento em código POO de propriedade (Get e Set) de C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

O código em questão serve para calcular o valor da área do circulo com o uso das palavras-chaves `get` e `set`.

Depois que eu ocorreu o erro CS1729 foi criado um construtor para corrigi-lo

```
private double valor;

    public CirculoApp(double valor)
    {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
```

Quando eu executo o código a seguinte saída é mostrada:

```
Digite o raio do círculo 1: 5
Digite o raio do círculo 2: 6
Digite o raio do círculo 3: 7

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

O erro aparece na linha 14:

```
public double Raio
    {
        get => Raio; X
        set => Raio = value;
    }
X = System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'
```

Aqui está o código.

```
using static System.Console;

public class CirculoApp
{
    private double valor;

    public CirculoApp(double valor)
    {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public double Raio
    {
        get => Raio;
        set => Raio = value;
    }

    public double Area
    {
        get => Area;
        set => Area = 3.14159 * Raio * Raio;
    }

    public string toString() => Raio + " " + Area + " ";
}

public class PropCirculoApp
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo 1: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var valor)) return 1;
        var circulo1 = new CirculoApp(valor);
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo 2: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out valor)) return 1;
        var circulo2 = new CirculoApp(valor);
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo 3: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out valor)) return 1;
        var circulo3 = new CirculoApp(valor);
        WriteLine(circulo1.toString());
        WriteLine(circulo2.toString());
        WriteLine(circulo3.toString());
        ReadKey();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu te dei do jeito certo, simples e correto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/413057/101. O erro só aconteceu porque resolveu alterar de forma errada. Não só não tem o erro como é mais simples.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Aplicação de área do círculo: método mostra que nem todos os caminhos do código retornam valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/413055/aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-%c3%a1rea-do-c%c3%adrculo-m%c3%a9todo-mostra-que-nem-todos-os-caminhos-do-c%c3%b3digo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema acontece porque no fragmento:

```
public double Raio
{
    get => Raio;
    set => Raio = value;
}
```

Você está instruindo ao compilador que ao usar o método assessor `get` ele retorne a si mesmo gerando uma auto recurção sem fim que termina em um estouro da pilha de chamadas.

O mesmo problema ocorre aqui:

```
public double Area
{
    get => Area;
    set => Area = 3.14159 * Raio * Raio;
}
```

Para corrigir esse problema basta adequar a chamada usando o campo `valor`, que você já declarou no código, cujo o intuito é armazenar o raio do círculo.

```
using static System.Console;

public class CirculoApp
{
    private double valor;
    

    public CirculoApp(double valor)
    {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public double Raio
    {
        // Use dado contido no campo valor como o raio.
        get => valor;
        set => valor = value;
    }

    public double Area
    {
        //Aqui não é necessário o set pois a finalidade da propriedade é retornar o resultado do cálculo de área.
        get => 3.14159 * Raio * Raio;
    }

    public string toString() => Raio + " " + Area + " ";
}

public class PropCirculoApp
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo 1: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var valor)) return 1;
        var circulo1 = new CirculoApp(valor);
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo 2: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out valor)) return 1;
        var circulo2 = new CirculoApp(valor);
        Write("Digite o raio do círculo 3: ");
        if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out valor)) return 1;
        var circulo3 = new CirculoApp(valor);
        WriteLine(circulo1.toString());
        WriteLine(circulo2.toString());
        WriteLine(circulo3.toString());
        ReadKey();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Resultando:

> Digite o raio do círculo 1: 3
>
> Digite o raio do círculo 2: 5
>
> Digite o raio do círculo 3: 7
>
> 3 28.27431
>
> 5 78.53975
>
> 7 153.93791

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/InconsequentialSnarlingKeyboardmacro#main.cs)</sup>

Comment: Agora entendi, obrigado.