# Impressão de um array com todos elementos na mesma linha

Tags: javascript, array, string

Por que quando montamos uma *array*, como no seguinte código:

```
let x = 0
let array7 = new Array
for(x = 0; x < 50; x++){

    array7[x] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 - 10 + 10)

}

let array8 = array7.filter(array7 => array7 < 20)
console.log(array7)
console.log(array8)
```

a saída da *array* montada é toda cheia de quebras de linhas? Tem como corrigir isso e mostrar o resultado em uma linha? Saída atual:

[image: Saída atual]

Resumindo, por que a saída é assim, e como faço para os elementos do *array* serem impressos todos na mesma linha?

Comment: onde você fez essa saída assim?

Comment: Isso quem fez é quem está dando a saída. Não tem código que resolva.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você está usando um recurso inadequado. Uma das coisas que poucas pessoas entendem é que há o dado e há a representação textual do dado. JS, assim como outras linguagens, possuem uma função [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) que entrega a representação textual do objeto. Quando você manda imprimir um dado ele pega essa representação textual. Já falei em [detalhes sobre isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101).

Acontece que a representação textual nem sempre é adequada para mostrar para o usuário da aplicação. Isso funciona bem com valores escalares, que são os dados simples muitas vezes considerados primitivos. Quando o dado é composto fica mais complicado definir como deveria ser a representação textual dele e em cada situação pode precisar representar de uma forma diferente, então para dados compostos a representação textual padrão fornecida só serve para efeitos de depuração. Não é o fim do mundo usá-la para apresentar para o usuário se for exatamente o que deseja, mas no caso não é, então a solução é montar a apresentação do jeito que deseja.

A pergunta não fala explicitamente mas me pareceu claro que queria que os valores deveriam ser apresentados um a um em uma linha, provavelmente separado por vírgula e por isso dou a solução abaixo.

Tem várias formas, uma delas é usando o [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
let array7 = new Array;
for (let x = 0; x < 50; x++) array7[x] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 - 10 + 10);
let array8 = array7.filter(array7 => array7 < 20)
console.log(array7.join(", "));
console.log(array8.join(", "));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Format.js).

Comment: Se a pessoa que negativou me disser o que está errado eu conserto.

Comment: muito obrigado, conhecia a função join mas não pensei em usar neste caso, tu me recomendaria outra forma de gerar vários números aleatórios para um array sem ser utilizado ciclos de repetição?

Comment: @gmtlme depende da necessidade.