# Como posso fazer o set de contactos de um objeto Telefone?

Tags: java, array, objetos

Na classe `Pessoa` declarei um *array* do tipo `Telefone` que armazena 3 contatos de telefone no set referido abaixo ele para cada contacto atribui um tipo e um nímero.

Estou com um problema em que quero atribuir a uma pessoa um novo tipo e `número` usando o `setContactos()` referido na classe teste abaixo.

```
    public class Pessoa{
        private Telefone[] contactos;
        //....
        public void setContactos(Telefone[] cont) {
        for (int i = 0; i < contactos.length; i++) {
            contactos[i].setNumero(cont[i].getNumero());
            contactos[i].setTipo(cont[i].getTipo());
         }
       }
       //....
    }

    public class Teste {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Telefone t1 = new Telefone("Casa", 123456);
            Telefone t2 = new Telefone("telemovel", 123456);
            Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("Marta Pereira");

            p1.setNIF(3454543);
            p1.setContactos(t1); //erro incompatible types: Telefone cannot be converted to Telefone[];  

            System.out.println(p1.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem algumas opções, uma se adéqua mais ao nome e [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) do método e a outra mais ao que normalmente se faz, e uma variação desta.

A primeira forma é você criar um *array* com esses telefones (mesmo que tenha apenas um tem que criar esse *array*) e então passar o *array*, afinal o método espera isto. Isso tem alguns problemas como [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101). Algo assim:

```
Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("Marta Pereira");
p1.setNIF(3454543);
p1.setContactos(new Telefone[] { new Telefone("Casa", 123456), new Telefone("telemovel", 123456) });
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/AggregateObjects.java).

Se for fazer isso eu acho que deveria estar no [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

A segunda forma, mais correta conceitualmente, é mudar o método para `adicionarTelefone()` e receber como parâmetro apenas `Telefone` e aí dentro deste método você adiciona o telefone em uma lista (não *array*), e então chama este método com cada telefone.

Nada impede de já aceitar pelo menos um telefone no construtor, e quem sabe uma lista inicial.

Precisa ser uma [lista](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) para que possa ir adicionando novos telefones e não ficar de tamanho fixo.

Deveria ter os métodos `RemoverTelefone()` e talvez `ModificarTelefone()` mas esse último é mais complicado, eu acho que nem vale o esforço.

Note que mudei o nome do método usando `Telefone` e não `Contato` porque não é um contato que está adicionando, contato é uma informação mais ampla.

Me parece que está obcecado por uso de *getters* e *setters*, não é culpa sua, tem um pessoal que espalha essa *fake news* e muita gente compra como se fosse uma maravilha. Não que não deva usar nunca, mas não é para usar como ensinam por aí, quase sempre o uso dele é errado. Comece estudar mais por [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101) já feita.

Uma outra forma seria fazer mais ou menos a mesma coisa, mas em vez de criar um objeto `Telefone` e passar esse objeto para o método deve passar os dados do telefone e o objeto ser criado internamente. Isto [tem vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Tenho certeza que está abusando do [`toString()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101) provavelmente aprendeu no mesmo material ruim.

Comment: Getters e setters são uma apólice de seguro falsa de modificação isolada, fazem sentido quando: 1-Em um setter, antes de atualizar o estado neste objeto de acordo com alguma entrada, validamos a entrada.
2 - O tipo de retorno de um getter é uma interface. Portanto, dissociamos a implementação da interface exposta, eu acho que de facto é algo ensinado por ai em muitos cursos Java/Android pra tornar informação "privada", sem explicar os conceitos de construção de um objeto e o porque de o fazer

Comment: Lendo clean code , tem uma referencia à isso no capitulo 6

Comment: Seu método funcionou bem. Obrigado

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @ScrapBench

Answer (score 1):

Conforme você mesmo informou, ocorre o erro:

*"erro incompatible types: Telefone cannot be converted to Telefone[];"*

Explicação do Erro:
O tipo Telefone não pode ser convertido para um array de Telefones.
O método **setContactos** aceita como parâmetro de entrada um **Array do tipo Telefone** e você está passando um objeto do tipo Telefone simples.

Possível solução:
Para solucionar esse problema, simplesmente passe o tipo correto para o seu método, que no caso é um array do tipo Telefone :

```
Telefone t1 = new Telefone("Casa", 123456);
Telefone t2 = new Telefone("telemovel", 123456);
Telefone[] contactos = new Telefone[] {t1, t2};
Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("Marta Pereira");
p1.setNIF(3454543);
p1.setContactos(contactos);
```

Comment: Obrigado funcionou na perfeição