# Criar métodos em classes para manipular os campos

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, propriedade, getters-setters

Fiz um código de uma associação binária entre duas classes `Cliente` e `Caixa`, **alguns métodos eu não pude entender como são inseridos no código de maneira lógica**, mas o código em si está funcionando, gostaria de uma ajuda pois o código está incompleto.

Os métodos faltantes estão marcados em retângulos vermelhos.

[image: ERD]

```
using static System.Console;

public class Cliente
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Saldo { get; set; }

    public Caixa caixa;

    public string GetNome()
    {
        return this.Nome;
    }

    public void SetNome(string Nome)
    {
        this.Nome = Nome;
    }

    public decimal GetSaldo()
    {
        return this.Saldo;
    }

    public void SetSaldo(decimal Saldo)
    {
        this.Saldo = Saldo;
    }

    public string toString()
    {
        return $"Cliente: {Nome} | Saldo: {Saldo}";
    }
}

public class Caixa
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string NomeOperador { get; set; }

    public Cliente cliente;

    public int GetCodigo()
    {
        return this.Codigo;
    }

    public void SetCodigo(int Codigo)
    {
        this.Codigo = Codigo;
    }

    public string GetNomeOperador()
    {
        return this.NomeOperador;
    }

    public void SetNomeOperador(string NomeOperador)
    {
        this.NomeOperador = NomeOperador;
    }

    public string toString()
    {
        return $"Código {Codigo} | Operador: {NomeOperador}";
    }
}

public class AppCaixa
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cliente _cliente = new Cliente();
        Caixa _caixa = new Caixa();

        Write("Digite o nome do cliente: ");
        _cliente.Nome = ReadLine();
        Write("Digite o nome do saldo do cliente: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal digitesaldo)) return 1;
        _cliente.Saldo = digitesaldo;

        Write("Digite o código do caixa: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out int digitecodigo)) return 1;
        _caixa.Codigo = digitecodigo;
        Write("Digite o nome do caixa: ");
        _caixa.NomeOperador = ReadLine();

        _cliente.caixa = _caixa;
        _caixa.cliente = _cliente;

        WriteLine($"{_caixa.toString()}");
        WriteLine($"{_cliente.toString()}");
        ReadKey();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é o que se chama métodos *getters/setter*. [Há controvérsias sobre seu uso e quase sempre as pessoas usam errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101) (leia tudo, incluindo os *links*). Em C# se quer reproduzi-los idiomaticamente deve-se usar propriedades, já que uma propriedade é a implementação da linguagem justamente para o *design pattern* chamado *getter/setter*. E já usou certo uma parte.

Acho que já falei que [o `ToString()` não serve para isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101). Vou mudar para algo que faça sentido. Neste caso poderia até deixar o `toString()` que não o mesmo que i `ToString()` que todo objeto tem, mas a intenção era ser isso, já que esse modelo foi feito pensando em outra linguagem, mas seria muito confuso.

Portanto esse modelo não faz muito sentido e é um exemplo ruim de como modelar algo, não o considere como algo para aprender bem.

A único coisa que deve fazer já que usou propriedade é eliminar esses métodos, simples assim (modifiquei nomes para atender o [padrão de nomenclatura do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101)):

```
using static System.Console;

public class Cliente {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Saldo { get; set; }
    public Caixa caixa;
    public string Imprimir() => $"Cliente: {Nome} | Saldo: {Saldo}";
    public Cliente(string nome) => Nome = nome;
}

public class Caixa {
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string NomeOperador { get; set; }
    public Cliente cliente;
    public string Imprimir() => $"Código {Codigo} | Operador: {NomeOperador}";
    public Caixa(int codigo) => Codigo = codigo;
}

public class AppCaixa {
    static int Main(string[] args) {
        Write("Digite o nome do cliente: ");
        var nome = ReadLine();
        var cliente = new Cliente(nome);
        Write("Digite o nome do saldo do cliente: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out decimal digiteSaldo)) return 1;
        cliente.Saldo = digiteSaldo;
        Write("Digite o código do caixa: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out int digiteCodigo)) return 1;
        var codigo = digiteCodigo;
        var caixa = new Caixa(codigo);
        Write("Digite o nome do caixa: ");
        caixa.NomeOperador = ReadLine();
        cliente.caixa = caixa;
        caixa.cliente = cliente;
        WriteLine($"{caixa.Imprimir()}");
        WriteLine($"{cliente.Imprimir()}");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IJ5LND). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1rIu6Q). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/GetterSetter.cs).

Answer (score 2):

O método com o mesmo nome da classe é o *construtor* da classe, que é o método executado quando se constrói um objeto da classe, usando o `new`, por exemplo `Cliente cli = new Cliente()`.

No seu exemplo, o construtor da classe `Cliente` recebe um nome como parâmetro, que é um atributo dessa classe, logo ele deve fazer o mesmo que o `setNome`:

```
public Cliente(string nome)
{
   this.nome = nome;
}
```

O mesmo raciocínio para a classe `Caixa`:

```
public Caixa(int codigo)
{
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
```

Os outros são get/set comuns, que devolvem/setam um tipo de uma classe, basta usar a mesma lógico dos outros get/set que já fez, por exemplo:

```
public void SetCaixa(Caixa caixa)
{
    this.caixa = caixa;
}

public Caixa GetCaixa()
{
    return this.caixa;
}


public void SetCliente(Cliente cliente)
{
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public Cliente GetCliente()
{
    return this.cliente;
}
```

Agora uma observação: para implementar um get/set, em C# não deve usar propriedades, pois elas em si já implementam isso para você.
O `public string Nome { get; set; }` em si já um get/set de nome.

Para fazer isso manualmente, deve declarar variáveis sem acesso fora da classe, que só possam ter acesso via os métodos de get/set, por isso podem ser `private`:

```
private string nome;

public string GetNome()
{
    return this.nome;
}

public void SetNome(string Nome)
{
    this.nome = nome;
}
```

Essa seria a forma correta de "encapsular a variável", que deve ser o conceito por trás disso que está fazendo. Essa implementação é muito comum em `Java` por exemplo, mas em `C#`, basta declarar a propriedade, como no seu exemplo `public string Nome { get; set; }` que faz isso, por isso o seu código de get/set está redundante com as propriedades, no lugar delas declare variáveis `private`, como o exemplo acima.