# Como formatar os minutos usando LocalDateTime em Java

Tags: java, data, datetime

Sou iniciante em Java e minha dúvida é na classe `LocalDateTime`.

O horário é registrado em um certo momento do programa. Quando mando escrever na tela, aparece assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu preciso que apareça com o número 0 antes do número 5, ou seja, com duas casas decimais.

Inserindo os dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mostrando os dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é criar um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), indicando o formato a ser usado:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter FMT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

public String toString() {
    System.out.println("Hora entrada: " + FMT.format(getHoraEntrada()) +
                       "\nHora saída: " + FMT.format(getHoraSaida()));
}
```

`"HH:mm"` indica o formato: `HH` são as horas (de 0 a 23) e `mm` são os minutos (de 0 a 59), ambos com um zero à esquerda caso o valor seja menor que 10. Veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) para saber todos os formatos possíveis.

Como as classes do [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/) são imutáveis e *thread-safe*, você pode criar o `DateTimeFormatter` como um campo estático da sua classe, por exemplo (como feito acima), assim não precisa criar um novo a cada vez que precisar formatar a data.

---

Outro detalhe é que, para criar um [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) contendo a data e hora atual, não precisa usar um *getter* para cada campo e depois construir outra instância com esses valores. No seu caso bastaria fazer:

```
data1 = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Se bem que no seu código você não setou os segundos e nem as frações de segundo, então o resultado do método [`of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-java.time.Month-int-int-int-) será um `LocalDateTime` com esses campos setados para zero. Se era essa a sua intenção, você pode truncar esses valores de um jeito mais simples:

```
data1 = LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

Desta forma, os segundos e frações de segundo serão zero (o mesmo resultado que você obteria usando o método `of` da maneira que usou - sem passar os valores desses campos).

O [`java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) indica para o método [`truncatedTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) que as unidades menores que a indicada serão zero. Como eu passei [`ChronoUnit.MINUTES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#MINUTES), as unidades menores que os minutos (no caso, os segundos e as frações de segundos) serão zero (mas se não era isso que queria e só precisa da data e hora atual, use `now()` e pronto).

---

Outra dica não diretamente relacionada ao problema: [Qual é a função do método `toString()`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/112052)

Comment: Entendi e funcionou perfeitamente como eu queria. Muito Obrigado!!

A função do método toString() era somente para teste. pra ver como seria a saída.