# Por que não consigo imprimir os valores de uma lista encadeada?

Tags: java

Preciso gerar uma lista encadeada vazia e fazer três operações com ela:

1. Adicionar um elemento ao final da lista
2. Remover da lista um elemento
3. Inserir n elementos ao final da lista

Por fim, os elementos devem ser objetos de uma classe `Elemento`. Deste modo eu criei a classe `Elemento`:

```
public class Elemento {

    private int valor;
    private int proximo = 0;

    Elemento(int pValor) {
        valor = pValor;
        proximo++;
    }
}
```

A classe da lista:

```
public class MinhaListaEncadeada {

    private ArrayList<Elemento> ListaEncadeada;
    private Elemento elemento;

    MinhaListaEncadeada() {
        ListaEncadeada = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void inserirElemento(int pValor) {
        ListaEncadeada.add(new Elemento(pValor));
    }

    public void removeElemento(int pValor) {
        for (int i=0; i<ListaEncadeada.size(); i++) {
            elemento = ListaEncadeada.get(i);
            if (elemento.equals(pValor))
                ListaEncadeada.remove(elemento);
        }        
    }

    public void insereNElementos(int n) {
        for (int i=1; i<n+1; i++)
            ListaEncadeada.add(new Elemento(i));
    }

    public void imprimeLista() {
        for (int i=0; i<ListaEncadeada.size(); i++) {
            if (i < ListaEncadeada.size()-1)
                System.out.print(ListaEncadeada.get(i) + ", ");
            else
                System.out.println(ListaEncadeada.get(i));
            }
        }
}
```

E por fim chamei seus métodos na `main` com alguns testes:

```
public class Exercicio3ListaEncadeada {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        MinhaListaEncadeada lista = new MinhaListaEncadeada();
        Elemento e;

        System.out.print("\n Inserindo o elemento 6 no final da lista: \n");
        lista.inserirElemento(6);
        lista.imprimeLista();

        System.out.print("\n Inserindo 6 elementos na lista: \n");
        lista.insereNElementos(6);
        lista.imprimeLista();

        System.out.print("\n Removendo o valor 4 na lista: \n");
        lista.removeElemento(4);
        lista.imprimeLista();
    }

}
```

Porém toda vez que eu executo o programa ele retorna:

```
Inserindo o elemento 6 no final da lista: 
exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@7229724f

 Inserindo 6 elementos na lista: 
exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@7229724f, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@16b98e56, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@7ef20235, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@27d6c5e0, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@4f3f5b24, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@15aeb7ab, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@7b23ec81

 Removendo o valor 4 na lista: 
exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@7229724f, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@16b98e56, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@7ef20235, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@27d6c5e0, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@4f3f5b24, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@15aeb7ab, exercicio3listaencadeada.Elemento@7b23ec81
```

Ao invés dos valores armazenados nos elementos. Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque ao imprimir um objeto, implicitamente é chamado o método `toString()` do mesmo. Como no seu caso a classe `Elemento` não possui este método, então ela usa [o que foi herdado de `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), que o imprime da forma que você viu.

Mas no seu caso, como você quer imprimir o valor do elemento, bastaria indicar isso explicitamente. Supondo que a classe `Elemento` possui o respectivo *getter*:

```
public class Elemento {
    private int valor;

    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
}
```

Bastaria fazer:

```
public void imprimeLista() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ListaEncadeada.size(); i++) {
        if (i < ListaEncadeada.size() - 1)
            System.out.print(ListaEncadeada.get(i).getValor() + ", ");
        else
            System.out.println(ListaEncadeada.get(i).getValor());
    }
}
```

---

Outro detalhe é que o seu método que remove tem 2 problemas. Um é que você está comparando um `Elemento` com um `int`, e nunca serão iguais. Na verdade o que você quer é comparar o valor do elemento, então seria `if (elemento.getValor() == pValor) { remove }`.

O outro problema é que ele não remove todas as ocorrências do valor. Por exemplo, se eu fizer:

```
MinhaListaEncadeada lista = new MinhaListaEncadeada();
lista.inserirElemento(4);
lista.inserirElemento(4);
lista.removeElemento(4);
lista.imprimeLista();
```

Isso vai imprimir (assumindo que o método `imprimeLista` já foi corrigido):

```
4, 4
4
```

Esse problema ocorre porque você está removendo elementos da lista ao mesmo tempo em que itera sobre ela. Ao remover o primeiro 4, o tamanho da lista passa a ser 1, e na segunda iteração o `i` vale 1 e ele sai do `for`. O jeito correto de remover todas as ocorrências do mesmo valor é usando um [`java.util.Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html):

```
public void removeElemento(int pValor) {
    Iterator<Elemento> it = ListaEncadeada.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next().getValor() == pValor)
            it.remove();
    }
}
```

Ou, a partir do Java 8:

```
public void removeElemento(int pValor) {
    ListaEncadeada.removeIf(e -> e.getValor() == pValor);
}
```

Mas se a ideia é remover **somente a primeira ocorrência** do elemento, uma alternativa seria interromper o *loop* após a primeira remoção:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if (it.next().getValor() == pValor) {
        it.remove();
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Outra alternativa para imprimir corretamente é sobrescrever o método `toString()` na classe `Elemento`:

```
public class Elemento {    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(this.valor);
    }
}
```

Aí você não precisa mudar o método `imprimeLista`, pois ao imprimir o `Elemento`, já será impresso o seu respectivo valor. Só tome cuidado para não abusar do `toString` e colocar informações demais nele (leia mais a respeito em ["Qual é a função do método `toString()`?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/112052)).

---

Também recomendo mudar o nome da variável para `listaEncadeada` (com a primeira letra minúscula), para ficar aderente às convenções de código do Java.

Comment: Muito obrigado =] O getValor resolveu o problema mesmo