# Sobrescrita do ToString csharp boas práticas

Tags: c#

Vejo em alguns programadores optando por fazer a sobrescrita do `ToString` em C# dentre alguns casos, minha dúvida, é uma má prática fazer o override deste em específico ou mesmo depende do programador decidir?

Exemplo:

```cs
public string FirstName { get; private set; }
public string LastName { get; private set; }

public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "método **reservado**"?

Comment: Melhorei/foquei a pergunta. Referente se é uma boa ou má pratica fazer o override no ToString ou é de escolha do dev e situação.

Comment: Depende, qual o objetivo em fazer override deste método? Existe a necessidade mesmo?

Comment: Esse código pertence a outra pessoa, no qual não tenho contato para saber porque dessa implementação e código postado é a totalidade da classe.

Comment: Ao meu ver, perde total coerência sobrescrever ele, pois um simples `ToString` não está orientando que será retornado o nome completo. Porém o conceito de sobrescrever o `ToString` cria uma dubiedade para mim em saber se há casos onde pode ser uma boa prática ou não.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/112052 <-- apesar de ser em Java, a ideia geral é a mesma (mas vc também pode ver [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42396672), essa sim específica pra C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendo direto é mais uma questão de objetividade, fazer um override do método não é errado nem certo, tudo depende do intuíto do seu projeto, se há necessidade ou não, ***mas se tratando de boas práticas o ideal é sempre extender as funcionalidades e não sobrescreve-las, mas creio que também não podemos levar a ferro e fogo tudo então vale uma avaliação conjunta do teammate.***

Answer (score 1):

Como boas práticas devemos sempre evitar uma sobrescrita. Ainda mais no método ToString() que com certeza será inevitavelmente muito utilizado em seu projeto.

Embora a Microsoft mostre como fazer, não significa que é uma boa prática e sim como um exemplo.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method

Você pode usar a classe StringExtensions para criar métodos personalizados para trabalhar com strings:

```js
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToCompleteFullName(this string input)
    {
        return $"{input} {FirstName} {LastName}";
    }
}
```

E para chamar o método seria simples assim:

```js
string teste = "Full name:";

teste = teste.ToCompleteFullName();
```

Comment: E quem define o que é ou não uma "boa prática"?