# Como imprimir objetos que estão em um Map?

Tags: dart, map

Testando algumas coisas sobre a funcionalidade [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-core/Map-class.html) não consegui entender como obter o **valor** do `Map` quando o mesmo é *setado* através de uma classe:

```
class Idade {
  int idade;

  Idade(this.idade);
}

void main() {
  Map<String, Idade> pessoas = Map();
  pessoas['Fulano'] = Idade(48);
  pessoas['Ciclano'] = Idade(19);
  
  print(pessoas.keys);     // (Fulano, Ciclano)
  print(pessoas.values);   <= Dúvida aqui
}
```

Se dou um `print(pessoas.values)` é retornado uma instância da classe `Idade`

> (Instance of 'Idade', Instance of 'Idade')

Se tenho uma instância da classe, porque simplesmente não consigo fazer:

```
print(pessoas.values.idade); // ERRO
```

Tentei de várias formas imprimir a idade mas todas dão erro, como pode ser testado neste [link](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true).

```
print(pessoas.values.idade); // ERRO
print(pessoas.idade);        // ERRO
```

Como poderia estar obtendo o valor nesse `Map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os erros são identificados pelo compilador.

Não existe uma propriedade chamada `value`, nem mesmo uma chamada `idade` no objeto `Map`. Propriedades não aparecem do nada. Ceja a [documentação do objeto](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-core/Map-class.html) quais propriedades existem em nele.

[`values`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-core/Map/values.html) existe. E a documentação dessa propriedade indica que ela retorna um objeto `Iterable<V>`. Então as únicas propriedades que pode acessar são as que estão na [documentação desse objeto](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-core/Iterable-class.html), não pode acessar propriedades de outro objeto.

Esse objeto serve para iterar, ou seja, para pegar os objetos que estão dentro dele, por exemplo varreu ele com um *loop* que entende como manipulá-lo. Também pode fazer manualmente, mas precisa saber fazer, e corre risco de errar. Fazendo isso vai pegando cada um dos objetos dentro desse objeto, e aí pode acessar os campos desse objeto final que deseja.

Assim funciona:

```
import 'dart:io';
 
class Idade {
    int idade;
    Idade(this.idade);
}

void main() {
    Map<String, Idade> pessoas = Map();
    pessoas['Fulano'] = Idade(48);
    pessoas['Ciclano'] = Idade(19);
    print(pessoas.keys);
    print(pessoas.values);
    for (var pessoa in pessoas.values) {
        print(pessoa.idade);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/XWrePp). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/aiundlcvzq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/ListMap.dt).

Note a diferença em acessar um objeto que tem **pessoas* e um que tem **uma pessoa**. Embora eu acho que o nome `pessoas`, e consequentemente `pessoa` estão errados, porque você tem apenas idades ali, e não pessoas. Mas preferi não consertar esse erro.

É possível acessar elementos individuais, ou usar alguma biblioteca que faça o serviço, mas tem que acessar via um objeto `Iterable`. O que o `print()` faz é imprimir o que o `Map`  entrega, e ele só pode chamar o `toString()` do objeto dentro dele para dar o resultado. O seu tipo não tem um `toString()` específico então ele usa o padrão que é dar o nome do tipo.

Você pode fazer isso funcionar como deseja criando um `toString()` no `Idade` que devolva o que deseja, mas não é fácil em caso assim dizer se isso é certo ou errado. Leia [Qual é a função do método toString()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101), vale para todas linguagens. Cuidado para não curar o paciente com uma outra doença.

Comment: Perfeitamente compreendido, quanto a explanação no começo da resposta sobre não **`existir value`** foi um erro de digitação aqui no site e seria `values` mesmo, editei a pergunta ajeitando isso, se quiser editar a resposta tbm fique a vontade. Quanto a parte de pessoas ali, é que apenas inseri a idade na classe pra simplificar já que não era o foco, mas, mesmo assim acredito que uma pessoa poderia ser formada  pela associação de um nome e uma idade não?! Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.

Comment: Poderia sim, não mexi nisso porque achei que não era relevante para a questão. Se em vez de `Idade`, tiver um `Pessoa` é certo que um `toString()` não é uma solução boa.