# __str__() não retorna o conteudo do objeto, mas o endereço na memória - Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Estou criando um programa para controle de estoque.

No código abaixo, não consigo fazer com que eu receba o valor da "lista de produtos".

```
lista_de_produtos = []

class Estoque:
    def __init__(self, lista_de_produtos):
        self.lista_de_produtos = lista_de_produtos
```

**essa parte**

```
def __str__(self):  
return str(self.lista_de_produtos)
```

**acima**

```
class Produto:
    def __init__(self, id, nome, quantidade):
        self.id = id
        self.nome = nome
        self.quantidade = quantidade 
       
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    # Estoca o produto na lista de estoque
    def estoca(self):
        lista_de_produtos.append(self)
```

Usando um `print(estoque)`, eu recebo "<**main**.Produto object at 0x000001E39674BA60>" e não o conteúdo do objeto.

O que posso fazer? Na classe `Produto`, isso funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você imprime um objeto (`print(objeto)`), internamente é chamado o método `__str__` deste objeto.

Então se eu fizer isso:

```py
class Produto:
    def __init__(self, id, nome, quantidade):
        self.id = id
        self.nome = nome
        self.quantidade = quantidade 
       
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

p = Produto(1, 'item1', 10)
print(p) # chama p.__str__()
```

Irá imprimir "item1", que é o resultado de chamar o método `__str__` no objeto `p`.

Mas se `p` estiver dentro de uma lista, aí não funciona mais. Ou seja, este código:

```py
# usa a mesma classe Produto o mesmo objeto "p" acima
lista = [ p ]
print(lista)
```

O resultado será algo como `[<__main__.Produto object at 0x7f64d91251c0>]`. Isso acontece porque agora o que está sendo chamado é `lista.__str__`, e ele não usa o método `__str__` dos elementos, e sim o método `__repr__`. Basta criar este método na classe `Produto` para vermos a diferença:

```py
class Produto:
    def __init__(self, id, nome, quantidade):
        self.id = id
        self.nome = nome
        self.quantidade = quantidade 
       
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'repr:' + self.nome

p = Produto(1, 'item1', 10)
lista = [ p ]
print(lista)
```

Agora o resultado será `[repr:item1]`. Então se quer que, ao imprimir a lista, ele também imprima o nome dos produtos, você poderia alterar o método `__repr__` para que este retorne `self.nome`, tal qual o método `__str__` está fazendo.

Mas vale lembrar o que a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) diz sobre `repr`:

> *For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`*

Ou seja, o método `__repr__` deveria retornar algo como `Produto(1, 'item1', 10)`. Claro que isto é uma recomendação, não quer dizer que você seja obrigado a seguir à risca, mas aí você estaria fazendo algo fora do "esperado" (se bem que [o próprio método `__str__` retornar apenas o nome já é algo passível de discussão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/112052)).

---

Outra alternativa é fazer com que o estoque retorne somente os nomes, sem depender da implementação específica do produto:

```py
class Estoque:
    def __init__(self, lista_de_produtos):
        self.lista_de_produtos = lista_de_produtos

    def __str__(self):  
        return str([ p.nome for p in self.lista_de_produtos ])
```

Ou seja, eu crio outra lista somente com os nomes dos produtos. Claro que você também poderia fazer `return str([ str(p) for p in self.lista_de_produtos ])`, assim ele retorna uma lista contendo seja lá qual for o retorno de `str(p)`, e aí você precisa decidir o que faz mais sentido. Usando `p.nome`, o estoque sempre retornará uma lista com os nomes dos produtos. Usando `str(p)`, o retorno vai mudar sempre que a classe `Produto` alterar o comportamento do seu método `__str__`. Veja o que faz mais sentido no seu caso.

---

Aproveitando, eu mudaria algumas coisas. Não acho que faz sentido um produto saber a sua quantidade (quem sabe isso é o estoque), e fica meio estranho um produto se adicionar em um estoque (pior ainda, ele se adiciona em uma lista global, que pode nem estar atrelada a um estoque).

Uma sugestão seria algo do tipo:

```py
class Estoque:
    # estoque começa vazio (poderia até começar com uma lista de produtos pré-definida, mas enfim, vamos simplificar por enquanto)
    def __init__(self):
        # produtos é um dicionário que mapeia cada produto para a sua quantidade
        self.produtos = {}

    # retorna os nomes dos produtos e suas respectivas quantidades
    def __str__(self):  
        return str([ (prod.nome, qtd) for prod, qtd in self.produtos.items() ])

    def estocar(self, produto, quantidade):
        # se o produto já existe, incrementa a quantidade já existente; senão, adiciona o produto
        if produto not in self.produtos:
            self.produtos[produto] = quantidade
        else:
            self.produtos[produto] += quantidade

class Produto:
    def __init__(self, id, nome):
        self.id = id
        self.nome = nome

    # métodos necessários para que o Produto seja usado como chave de um dicionário
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict
    # https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id

estoque = Estoque()
estoque.estocar(Produto(1, 'item 1'), 5)
estoque.estocar(Produto(2, 'item 2'), 30)

p = Produto(3, 'item 3')
estoque.estocar(p, 10)
print(estoque)

# aumentar quantidade de um produto
estoque.estocar(p, 90)
print(estoque) # agora a quantidade do item 3 é 100
```

Mas claro, a forma correta de fazer depende dos requisitos.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e pelas dicas. Estou bolando esse projeto do zero e realmente não tenho experiência com isso.

Comment: @PauloFeresin Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.

Comment: Resolveu sim, já marquei a sua resposta. Obrigado novamente.