# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: string, dart, null

Quando tento passar para o `toString()` ele dá erro pois o valor pode ser nulo, como faço pra corrigir isso?

```
class User {
  String? name;
  String? mail;
  String? password;
  bool? keepOn;

  User({this.name, this.mail, this.password, this.keepOn});

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    mail = json['mail'];
    password = json['password'];
    keepOn = json['keepOn'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = name;
    data['mail'] = mail;
    data['password'] = password;
    data['keepOn'] = keepOn;
    return data;
  }

  String toString() {
    return "Name: " +
        name +
        "\nE-mail: " +
        mail +
        "\nPassword " +
        password;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisa garantir que o dado não é nulo. O ideal seria o objeto já nem aceitar isso, mas pode ser que seu problema permita aceitar, é uma situação ruim, mas se o requisito for esse não tem o que fazer.

Se tentar imprimir algo nulo o que vai acontecer? Precisa dar um tratamento para isto.

Então a solução é dizer para o compilador que você está tratando o dado e não usá-lo diretamente se ele for nulo. Tem inúmeras formas de fazer isso, uma delas é usando o operador `??`, onde ele pega um valor se o operando anterior é nulo. Se fizer isso o compilador entende que você deu um tratamento e não dará erro. Eu escolhi imprimir um texto vazio, pode ser que queira escrever alguma outra coisa.

```
String toString() {
    return "Name: " +
        (name ?? "") +
        "\nE-mail: " +
        (mail ?? "") +
        "\nPassword: " +
        (password ?? "");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/hampbmcaxh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/Nullable.dt).

Nem sempre o [`toString()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101) deveria ser usado assim.

Answer (score 0):

*The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'*

Esta informando que o tipo de argumento passado é uma **String**  esse é um tipo de dados opcional **MAS** o tipo de parâmetro aguardado é uma String obrigatório.

Esta tentando passar um valor que pode ser nulo e o compilador informa que não é possível atribuir um valor opcional a um tipo de dado obrigatório.

```
String toString() {
  return "Name: " +
      (this.name != null ? this.name : "") +
      "\nE-mail: " +
      (this.mail != null ? this.mail : "") +
      "\nPassword " +
      (this.password != null ? this.password : "");
}
```

O operador ternário `?` vai averiguar se a variável é null quando for constada vai retornar  `""`

`this` não é necessário já que  o escopo da classe já é implícito em todo o método, só foi usado sem maiores pretensões apenas para mostrar uma resposta.
Dessa forma evitando passa valores nulos.